# how to make the bot delete the uppercase discord python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a bot to avoid capitalization but I can't do it
When I write a number or ":" it detects it as capital letters
here is my python code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='') #ive tried both true/false. neither works 

print("Starting...")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged on as {0.user}".format(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
    if message.content.startswith(message.content.upper()):
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, " ".join(args))

bot.run("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just change

```
if message.content.startswith(message.content.upper()):
```

to

```
if message.content.isupper():
```

to detect capitalization, assuming `message.content` is a string

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto user696969's answer, here's my solution

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.isupper():
        await message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, message.content.lower())
```

in case you want to use the up-to-date version of python-discord, here you go

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.isupper():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(message.content.lower())
```

if you don't want D: to be detected as 'all caps', here's my suggestion

```
if message.content.isupper() and len(set(message.content)) > 3: #to have at least 3 unique characters
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now when I write "D:" it jumps to me that it is capital letters, how could I correct that?

Comment: @PeliculasYSeries add on another condition to make an 'and statement'.  It's really subjective on how you want to condition it